# Testing a "transition page" with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following site flow:

Home Page -> 
Fill out input forms ->
Click search ->
Transition/Loading page ->
Results page

Now, I have to test that something is happening on the Transition/Loading page which basically does a redirect when the search is finished.

If I am on the Transition/Loading page I can click ESC to stop the flow so you don't go on the Results page.

Right now we have a condition that waits for the presence of a div inside the Transition/Loading page but sometimes this page run so fast that the condition fails because we are already on the Results page.

Do you think there is some way to stop on the browser on the waiting page?

Comment: Since the loading page redirects to the Results page, it must have an "src" attribute. You can set it to null using JavascriptExecutor so that the redirection doesn't happen to the Result's page. ( FYI, It's not concrete, just a guess. You can give it a shot though)